# mysqli_multi_query not getting executed multiple times inside a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

In my php code I use a while loop as shown below.

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","entries");
$query1="select * from jobs";
$query1exe=mysqli_query($connection,$query1);
$loopcount=0;
while($query1collector=mysqli_fetch_array($query1exe,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $query2="insert into learning set name='new_1';
    insert into learning set name='new_2';";
    mysqli_multi_query($connection,$query2);
    $loopcount++;
}
echo($loopcount);
?>
```

In this code I get the output as 104($loopcount) which means the loop was executed 104 times. But in my table named learning I have only two new entries new_1 and new_2. I expected 208 new entries (new_1 104 times and new_2 104 times). Why didn't I get the result expected.

I am using PHP Version 5.5.11

P.S I want to use the mysqli_multi_query itself as I need to execute a few queries simultaneously.

This is how my learning table look like when I executed my code three times

```
--------------------------------------------------------
slno     | name       | city       | Phone
--------------------------------------------------------
1        | sandeep    | NULL       | NULL
-------------------------------------------------------
2        | new_1      | NULL       | NULL
-------------------------------------------------------
3        | new_2      | NULL       | NULL
-------------------------------------------------------
4        | new_1      | NULL       | NULL
-------------------------------------------------------
5        | new_2      | NULL       | NULL
------------------------------------------------------
6        | new_1      | NULL       | NULL
------------------------------------------------------
7        | new_2      | NULL       | NULL
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is there a unique index on the `name` column?

Comment: You don't need a loop, you can do this all in one SQL query. `INSERT INTO learning (name) SELECT 'new_1' FROM jobs UNION ALL SELECT 'new_2' FROM jobs`

Comment: @Barmar no. There isn't. I can see the new 'new_1' and 'new_2' entry each time I execute my code.

Comment: @Barmar 'new_1' is not a column name. It is just a text input

Comment: I know that, that's why I put it in quotes in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Check for errors from `mysqli_multi_query`. Maybe you're getting a "commands out of sync" error.

Comment: post schema for `learning` table please. probably you have `UNIQUE` key against `name` column there

Comment: @Barmar How to check for the error? No errors are being displayed on my page by default

Comment: @Alex I have posted the structure of learning table

Comment: That is not structure, that is data stored. but ok, I see that you have duplicates there

Comment: @SandeepThedarkprinceC It will return `false` if the first query gets an error. You have to call `mysqli_next_result()` to get the result of the second query. If either of these returns `false`, use `echo mysqli_error($connection);` to see the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I watched on the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php) and found a user comment

> if you mix $mysqli->multi_query and $mysqli->query, the latter(s) won't be executed!

Use only `mysqli_query`, split your multi-queries into this:

```
mysqli_query($connection,"insert into learning set name='new_1'");
mysqli_query($connection,"insert into learning set name='new_2'");
```

Comment: The insert statement won't run even in phpmyadmin

Comment: I have a few queries that are used to extract the value of some variables and I execute my main query based on the values of those variables. Thats the reason why I am interested in multi_query

Comment: @bksi Possible. I didn't tested it. But i explained what the problem was and offered an workaround.

Comment: Hm how you can know if the query works if the query itself is wrong?

Comment: @bksi Because the questioner said that the inserting itself works. Citate: `But in my table named learning I have only two new entries new_1 and new_2.`

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to fetch the results of both queries before you can start another multi-query.

```
while($query1collector=mysqli_fetch_array($query1exe,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $query2="insert into learning set name='new_1';
    insert into learning set name='new_2';";
    mysqli_multi_query($connection,$query2) or die('insert new_1 error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    mysqli_next_result($connection) or die('insert new_2 error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    $loopcount++;
}
```

Comment: I got this error 
`insert new_1 error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: I must be psychic. I posted a comment yesterday saying you were probably getting that error.

Comment: The query was executed in the first loop and I have two entries as I have said and in the second loop I got this error

Comment: You were right. isn't there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I never use multi-query, so I'm not really sure what the right fix is.